# use secondary index to display data table in r

Tags: r, data.table

After using `setindex(dt,col1,col2)` to create the secondary indices, how to display the whole data table in col1 and/or col2 order? R examples only show how to extract certain rows based on col1 and/or col2 values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example by including (1) sample data, (2) code to reproduce what you've done/tried, (3) a clear problem statement including what you'd like to achieve/expected output. Perhaps take a look at how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you just want to look at the data - `print.data.frame(dt)` ?

Comment: indices don't sort the data in memory -- they only store the sort order to increase efficiency of subsequent operations using sorting. so the way to print in order with indices is the same as without -- only that the sorting will be faster  DT[order(index1, index2)] etc. to physically sort, use setkey